# How do you control relay using two different methods?

Tags: relay

I would like to control a relay using an esp8266 module sending the signal. However, I want to also have an optional push button in case my internet is down.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do this? Eg. Schematic etc.

This is the relay i'm using:
[image: Here is the relay I'm using]

This is my attempt at a block diagram:
[image: My attempt at a block diagram]

Comment: Why not put an on-off switch in parallel with the relay contact?

Comment: Is there somewhere online I can read into it? I'm confused about how the schematic would look.

Comment: @Yousuf Does it have to be a push button (push on, push off) or would a switch like a light switch be good?

Comment: Light switch would be just fine.

Comment: @Yousuf OK, please [edit] your question to add a block diagram of the circuit you have at the moment so that we can show you what to add and/or change.

Comment: that is not two ways to control a relay ... that is two ways of receiving data/signals ... what you do with the data, such as turning on a relay is actually a completely separate thing

Comment: If the switch is ON, do you want to still be able to control the relay with the ESP? Or does the switch override the ESP?

Comment: Ideally, the switch should override the ESP.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Is that what you were asking for in terms of block diagram? Fyi, I only have the concept of what I want. I haven't actually wired it up yet. I wanted to make sure there is a back up switch in case my internet is down first.

Comment: maybe on of the extra ESP pins can be used to command the ESP to switch the relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this schema on the following website:

https://www.hackster.io/yazsansh/affordable-alexa-enabled-iot-f7d638

The poster claimed that it would allow for activation by ESP as well as manually. So I will attempt to duplicate the schema with some minor adjustments (his relay has the Common at the bottom while mine is in the center):

[image]